# Jquery change css on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here I have an page and when i want to click on button I write a code to hide the content but there are error:

http://jsbin.com/EVEWOta/2/edit

and jquery code:

```
$('#button').click {
  $('#firstPage').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Comment: I also try with .destroy();

Comment: You could have solved this by reading [the doc](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Comment: Your function is malformed, but why use CSS and not `$('#firstPage').hide();`?

Comment: `.click` is a function. means we can pass arguments in it. Reading doc will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should Use `.on()` or `.click()` function in the right way! And also use `.hide()` instead of `.css()`

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
  $('#firstPage').hide();
});

$('#button').click(function() {
  $('#firstPage').hide();
});
```

Comment: `click` is just a shortcut for `on`, no? The common mistake is to use `bind` when you should use `on`, right? I'd go as far as to say it is better to use `click` instead of `on` cause it is shorter, more readable, and even kinda future-proof.

Comment: oh yeah your are absolutly right! click is the shortcut, anyway he had a mistake in his code for click!

Answer (score 2):

It will be like (With `.on()`)

```
$('#button').on('click',function(){
    $('#firstPage').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Or you can also simply write like (Without `.on()`)

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#firstPage').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  $('#firstPage').css('display', 'none');
})
```

Comment: thanks very much, work now

Answer (score 1):

You missed to add **handler**(eventObject)

Try this.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  $('#firstPage').css('display', 'none');
});
```

From you fiddle it seems,

`$('#firstPage').hide` is wrong

instead

```
$('#firstPage').hide();
```